# Given rate of events, what is the probability for a single event?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $f(t)$ be the (continuous) number of events per unit time. I want to extract the probability that in a range of time $[t_1,t_2]$ there will be a single event. Since $f$ is the number of events, it will not simply the integral. Should I just normalize $f$ by $\int\limits_{t_{min}}^{t_{max}}f\mathrm{d}t$, where $[t_{min},t_{max}]$ is the time interval of interest, to get the probability? I.e. is the expression
$$
P(t_1,t_2) = \frac{\int\limits_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\mathrm{d} t}{\int\limits_{t_{min}}^{t_{max}}f(t)\mathrm{d}t}
$$
the probability for a single event in the time interval $[t_1,t_2]$?

Answer (score 0):

I believe $f(t)$ represents the expected rate of events.
First calculate the expected number of events in the time interval:
$\nu=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f(t)\,dt$. Next calculate the Poisson probability that 1 event is observed when $\nu$ are expected: $p=\nu e^{-\nu}$.